# TFS and SharePoint 3.0 Upgrade

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I would like to upgrade our current Team Foundation Server 2010 & SharePoint 3.0 to new hardware. Currently running off a single server farm.

Is it possible to upgrade from our current system without interupting the service, we would like to trial the new version on a new VM Build to the required spec. Our upgrade is too TFS 2012 and SharePoint 2010, choosing the upgrade senario would clearly mess with our live production system.

When the system has been test run we could then snapshot back to installation and configure the upgrade process. Can anyone shed some light on the best way to go??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore a TFS backup to a separate testing server, then perform the upgrade there.  Just be sure to do the TFSConfig ChangeServerID command after you restore the backup.

Even though this blog is talking about TFS 2012 the process is essentially the same: http://cromwellhaus.com/2013/08/restoring-tfs-2012-to-sandbox/

Comment: Thank you very helpful! i am upgrading TFS 2012 with SharePoint 2010 to a new server so this is exactly what i was after! The changeServerID is just what i was looking for!

Comment: The article you linked to provides good info from a smart guy (we worked together a little over a year ago)... but an upgrade is still going to cause downtime/disruption during the migration.

Answer (score 0):

1) there *will* be a disruption of service during the (PROD) migration. It can be minimized to the period of time required for the database to be transferred, but there's no way to do some sort of live-migration

2) as a SP consultant that is also quite familiar with TFS (MCP and such), keep the two environments separate. Any integration you do perform should only be provided using service app connections. Too many bad memories of problems when they're tightly integrated, which happens when the two products are maintained by separate teams and release schedules.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i am very new to both TFS and SharePoint so this is a learning curve for myself. Its hard to find some real exmaples of live upgrades from 2010 to 2012! with sharepoint integrated in a single server farm. Would you recomend moving our current system to dedicated servers i.e SQL SERVER, SharePoint Server and TFS ? (Multiple Server Farm) Again thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Phil: I tend to recommend that the SharePoint farm for TFS be separate from an enterprise SharePoint farm. The release cycles for both products are entirely separate, and tight integration means more (frequent and widespread) pain during updates from both teams. If you want to benefit from some of the services (search, excel services, etc), then use connected service apps. Same benefit, but separate environments means separate maintenance cycles. Feel free to reach out to me directly if you'd like to have an in depth conversation.